Runtime upgrade on paseo testnet
anyone guide me how to do runtime upgrade on paseo testnet. I was doing runtime upgrade on tanssi by uploading uploading your Wasm runtime file from here. Do you think it is straight forward as in tanssi?

Any update? Otherwise I'll close this.

If you are a parachain of Paseo.
You should use parachainSystem.authorizeUpgrade and parachainSystem.enactAuthorizedUpgrade.
